# Rmarkdown citation_package: natbib, How to change 'and' to '&'

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

In writing a journal article I use rmarkdown with

```
citation_package: natlib
biblio-style: apelike
```

The references are printed according to the following format

> author1, T. J. and author2, Y. (2008). Articla Name, 26(3):1–22.

I would like to know how to change 'and' to '&' and how to add url to the references. In my bib file references are included.

Comment: If you check [**"here"**](https://stackexchange.com/sites) you can select a better fitting site for posting this question. It includes 'academia', 'biology', 'physics', 'law', 'math', 'politics', 'bioinformatics', etc. The latter one includes biopython and that has its fair share of NCBI, Pubmed, etc.

Comment: Your question isn't necessarily `rmarkdown` related but applies to Latex as a whole. Check that https://tex.stackexchange.com doesn't already have your answer regarding defining a custom bibliography file. From there, you can include the extension tex files in the rmarkdown document.